# Units of C[0,1]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We know that any $f\in C[0,1]$ with $f(x)\neq 0, \forall x\in [0,1]$, then $f$ is unit. Is there any other element in $C[0,1]$ which can become an unit?

Comment: How would you get rid of the zero?

Comment: Suppose $g\in C[0,1]$ is a unit and $g(c)=0$ for some $c\in[0,1]$. Then there is some $h\in C[0,1]$ with $(g\cdot h)(x)=1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. In particular, $0=g(c)h(c)=(g\cdot h)(c)=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Gae.S. I have the intuition but I am able to prove.

Comment: (Un)able to prove *what*?

Comment: Now its ok sir, @MichaelMorrow has done the job. Thanku